# How to Start/Stop/Wait for a Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, windows-runtime

I am porting some C# .Net code to WinRT and I am having trouble figuring out how to replace the following:

```
bool threadDone = false;
Thread updateThread = null;

void StartUpdateThread() {
  threadDone = false;
  updateThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SendUpdateThread));
  updateThread.Start();
}

void StopUpdateThread() {
  if (updateThread == null) return;
  threadDone = true;
  updateThread.Join();
  updateThread = null;
}

void SendUpdateThread() {
  while(!threadDone) { 
    ... 
    Thread.Sleep(...);
  }
}
```

What is the best way to replace this in WinRT. I have looked at ThreadPool.RunAsync(...) to start the code running, but I am not sure of the best wait to stop it and wait for its completion in StopUpdateThread. Also, what do I replace the sleep with in my thread function?

Comment: Threading is dead! Long live threading!

Comment: Then what do I replace it with? Essentially, I want to periodically (every N milliseconds) send out updates. Is there a better way to do this with WinRT?

Comment: Ingoring the trivial async/await answer, that's a difficult question to answer without more information. Send updates to whom? What do you do when you are tombstoned or shutdown unexpectedly

Comment: This is for a client of a networked game. The thread periodically checks for any changes since the last update sent out over the network, and sends the new changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we're talking about C# 5 GUI application, it would be probably best if you didn't block anything and used `Task`s and `async`-`await` instead. That could look something like this:

```
// I think this field needs to be volatile even in your version
volatile bool taskDone = false;
Task updateTask = null;

void StartUpdateTask() {
  taskDone = false;
  updateTask = Task.Run(SendUpdateTask);
}

async Task StopUpdateTask() {
  if (updateTask == null) return;
  taskDone = true;
  await updateTask;
  updateTask = null;
}

async Task SendUpdateTask() {
  while (!taskDone) { 
    ... 
    await Task.Delay(…);
  }
}
```

But to use this code correctly, you actually need to understand what `async`-`await` does, so you should read up about that.

Also, this might not be exactly what you need, but that's hard to know based just on the information in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the volatile suggestion.

Comment: One minor thing, in order for it to compile, I had to do the following: updateTask = Task.Run((Func<Task>)SendUpdateThread);