# Wait for a thread to complete in Metro

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

In Metro, may I know how do you wait for a thread to complete. In conventional desktop app, to wait for the thread to complete, I will use

`thread.Join()`

However, how about in Metro?

```
// public void getSignalProcessingRunnable(IAsyncAction source) {}
IAsyncAction ThreadPoolWorkItem = Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPool.RunAsync(getSignalProcessingRunnable);
// How to wait for thread to complete?
```

Using `await` won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `await` is not working, you can also try using [Task.WaitAny Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270672%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from MSDN

> **Task.WaitAny Method**, Waits for any of the provided Task objects to complete execution.

```
Task.WaitAny(ThreadPoolWorkItem.AsTask());
```

You can also refer to this link: [How to Start/Stop/Wait for a Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238662/how-to-start-stop-wait-for-a-thread)

Also have a look on this good reference [**No Threads for you ! (in metro style apps)**](http://www.jaylee.org/post/2012/03/17/No-Threads-for-you-in-metro-style-apps.aspx)

Comment: But in Metro, I am having IAsyncAction, not Task.

Comment: Then await keyword is your friend, why is it not working? What is happening?

Comment: The code just do not stop at await. The flow continue, although the thread is still running

Comment: Usually UI thread do not block at await and continue running but the Async thread waits at that point. May be this is what you are experiencing

Comment: You can also convert IAsyncAction to Task, see my edited answer.